# In-app update - infinite loop, even after restarting the app

Tags: android, android-update-app

I'm trying to implement [in app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java)

But the issue that when I test it I get the infinite installing which never ends, I press back button, it returns back to main screen of the app and instantly displaying update screen again with infinite  installing, restarting the app (including force stop), clearing the date + cache doesn't help - the update screen will popup again:

[image]

The code I use:

```
class InAppUpdateTestHelper(
    private val activity: Activity,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
    private val startUpdateFlowForResult: ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>,
) {
    private val appUpdateManager by lazy { AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(activity) }

    init {
        try {
            val defaultLifecycleObserver = object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
                    checkIfAppUpdateInProgress()
                }
            }
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(defaultLifecycleObserver)
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        forceUpdate()
    }

    private fun forceUpdate() {
        try {
            appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
                try {
                    val updateAvailable =
                        appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE

                    val isUpdateImmediateAllowed =
                        appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)

                    if (updateAvailable && isUpdateImmediateAllowed) {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            // an activity result launcher registered via registerForActivityResult
                            startUpdateFlowForResult,
                            AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                                .build()
                        )
                    }
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Timber.e("appUpdateInfo addOnFailureListener ${it.message}")
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun checkIfAppUpdateInProgress() {
        val startUpdateFlowForResult = startUpdateFlowForResult ?: return
        try {
            appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
                if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                            appUpdateInfo,
                            // an activity result launcher registered via registerForActivityResult
                            startUpdateFlowForResult,
                            AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                                .build()
                        )
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

the docs says that I should check if app is in update progress `onResume`, that's why I use `DefaultLifecycleObserver`. `lifecycleOwner` comes from activity:

```
private val startUpdateFlowForResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
        // handle callback
        if (DEBUG) {
            val resultCode = result.resultCode
            Timber.d("startUpdateFlowForResult $resultCode")
        }
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    inAppUpdateTestHelper = InAppUpdateTestHelper(
        activity = this,
        lifecycleOwner = this,
        startUpdateFlowForResult = startUpdateFlowForResult,
    )
}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

**Update**:

I was testing on Samsung S22 Android 14.

Then I tried Samsung S10 Android 12 and finally it worked fine.

I even tried to clear data + cache for Google Play on Samsung S22 Android 14 but still infinite installation...

Need to test Pixel Emulator on Android 14 then...